# Fitch Exercise 8.31 Proof

Tags: proof-verification, logic, natural-deduction

I am working on this proof and I have set it up. I'm not sure how I should proceed or if I am doing it correctly so far Thank you!

The first 3 lines before the horizontal line are the premises!
[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltrAP.png): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltrAP.png)

Comment: Could you post the original question as well?

Comment: The first 3 lines are the predicates!

Comment: @JasonWu You mean the premises?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yes sorry I mean premises

Comment: A better outline to proceed from would be to prove horned from contradiction rather than magical, and then horned immediately implies magical. (Magical has no involvement in anything else, so will only clutter things up.) Actually, by that same token, you should just proceed to prove "not mortal or mammal" from the first premise.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I understand the clutter aspect but I thought I need to use those to prove Magical(c)

Comment: You do, but "magical" follows immediately from "horned" by implication elimination. And "horned" follows immediately from "(not mortal) or mammal" by implication elimination. So all you really need to do is prove "(not mortal) or mammal". Only the first premise is relevant to that end. If you use excluded middle to split it up into cases of "mythical" and "not mythical", then either way "(not mortal) or mammal" holds.

Comment: @JasonWu To use $\lor$ Elim, you also need to prove $My(c)\lor\neg My(c)$, after that your approach works

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know the law of excluded middle. I want to continue with what I have now even thought it's sort of cluttered but I am assuming we have to start a subproof with not((not mortal) or mammal) and then 2 more nested sub proofs of each and use v elim to derive a contradiction?

Comment: (You have to address me with @ if you want me to get notified). You can start by showing "Mythical or (not mythical)" (this is an instance of excluded middle) and use $\lor$-elim from there. Proving excluded middle is a good exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follows your set up, here is another approach:

$$\boxed{\begin{align}
&\text{My(c):=Mythical(c)}\\
&\text{Ma(c):=Mammal(c)}\\
&\text{Mo(c):=Mortal(c)}\\
&\text{Ho(c):=Horned(c)}\\
&\text{Mg(c):=Magical(c)}\\
\end{align}}$$

---

[image]

Here is how to continue with what you have and finish the proof use $\lor$ Elim:

[image]

That proved $My(c)\lor\neg My(c)$ now we can use $\lor$ Elim.

[image]

Which will take a little more works.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\def\magic{\operatorname{Magical}}\def\mythic{\operatorname{Mythical}}$
Your basic idea is okay, but you cannot use $\vee$-elimination unless you have a disjunction; that is $\mythic(c)\vee\neg\mythic(c)$

If you cannot use the Law of Excluded Middle to assert this, then you can modify the proof to use another negation introduction.

$$\small\fitch{~\vdots}{\fitch{\neg\magic(c)}{\fitch{\mythic(c)}{~\vdots\\ \bot}\\\fitch{\neg\mythic(c)}{~\vdots\\ \bot}\\\color{red}\bot\quad\color{red}{\vee\mathsf E\text{ invalid}}}\\\neg\neg \magic(c)\quad\neg\mathsf I\\\magic(c)\qquad\neg\neg\mathsf E}\qquad\qquad\fitch{~\vdots}{\fitch{\neg\magic(c)}{\fitch{\mythic(c)}{~\vdots\\ \bot}\\\neg\mythic(c)\qquad\neg\mathsf I\\~\vdots\\ \bot}\\\neg\neg\magic(c)\quad\neg\mathsf I\\ \magic(c)\qquad\neg\neg\mathsf E}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to fix the proof: keep the subproof that assumes $Mythical(c)$ and ends with $\bot$. Close this subproof using $\neg \ Intro$ to get $\neg Mythical(c)$, and now you can do all the steps you originally did inside the subproof that assumed $\neg Mythical(c)$ to get to $\bot$, as desired. In other words, there is no need for two separate subproofs, and hence no need to prove the Law of Excluded Middle either.